# Is there a sample anywhere that extends the May2022 Microsoft Teams Javascript SDK sample that allows an http request bot to call the MS graph apis

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

Basically I want to post values in a spreadsheet stored as a teams tab from an externalised teams http endpoint

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you look at the samples in the current Teams SDK there is a bot sample that posts adaptive cards  but does not then interact with the MS Graph api in any meaningful fashion. I want to know how to extend it to interact with MS Graph specifically Worksheets in channels.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/index.html#javascript   https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/azure-resourcemanager-botservice_1.0.0-beta.4/sdk/botservice/azure-resourcemanager-botservice/